# How to avoid re-logging into my accounts each time, Selenium Python mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am learning Selenium (using my local machine) and need to use it to access my accounts (FB, gmail, etc) and would like to use it without having to input my user id and password each time.

Is there a way to either:

1) Have whatever instructions are in my script apply to my existing chrome session

2) Somehow have the new window that loads remember my user name/password (this seems like using an existing chrome session, but im not sure how)

**What I have so far :**

*(I am unsure if my profile should contain my saved credentials for websites like google and FB, but i don't see why not)*

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

This opens up a new window with some of my credentials, but crashes thereafter with error.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Mac OS X 10.9.5 x86_64)
```

Comment: FYI, I've found my chrome profile at `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default`.

Comment: Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("https:one_url.com")

time.sleep(1)

# Login to this one_url.com
username = browser.find_element_by_xpath("find username field")
password = browser.find_element_by_class_name("find password field")
username.send_keys("user")
password.send_keys("password")
login_attempt = browser.find_element_by_xpath("find submit button")
login_attempt.click()
time.sleep(5)

# enter into another web without login
browser.get("https://one_url/profile.com")
time.sleep(5)
# one more 
browser.get("https://one_url/profile.com")
time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Remember,do not close the browser

Answer (score 1):

In Java, we can do it by using ChromeOptions and Chrome Profile. In chrome navigate to chrome://version/ It will display profile path and Executable path.

As per my working on this, \Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3 is displaying when navigating to chrome://version/ in standard chrome. In this profile, I navigated to StackOverflow and saved credentials. So used below code

```
 Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    prefs.put("binary", "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "E:\\selenium_setups\\poi-3.12\\chromedriver.exe");
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();

    options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
    options.addArguments("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\murali\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Profile 3");
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);

    //WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com/");
```

As per my understanding, I excepted the stackoverflow.com page displayed as logged in. But for the first time, I am not logged in. so cross-checked with chrome://version/ in chrome opened by driver, profile path is displayed as
\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3\Default. Then logged manually in that profile itself, which is opened by webdriver and executed gain by closing it.

Finally, the page is displayed as logged in. So it may be in java. I hope it will help you to try in python.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

if you using Mac, you should change to --user-data-dir path.
You can change your code;

```
chrome_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome")
```

Remove the "Default/" from the end of your path.